# How to get all the elements in an array by dynamic property name?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with some key value data.

```
var data = [
    {
        speed : 130,
        acceleration: 3.8
    },
    {
        speed : 120,
        acceleration: 3
    },
    {
        speed : 90,
        acceleration: 1.2
    },
    {
        speed : 140,
        acceleration: 1.4
    },
]
```

I would like to get all the 'speed' items into different array. I could use data.map(x => x.speed) but here I do not know the key name.

I want to something like

```
var extract = getSubArray(data, 'speed');
```

Comment: Inside `getSubArray`, you can use your `map` with bracketed property access; see the linked question's answers. E.g., `function getSubArray(data, propName) { return data.map(x => x[propName]); }` or with ES2015+ destructuring: `function getSubArray(data, propName) { return data.map(([propName]: value) => value); }` though...yeah, I guess destructuring isn't really helpful there. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add that logic in a function:

```js
var data = [{
    speed: 130,
    acceleration: 3.8
  },
  {
    speed: 120,
    acceleration: 3
  },
  {
    speed: 90,
    acceleration: 1.2
  },
  {
    speed: 140,
    acceleration: 1.4
  },
]

function getSubArray(dataArr, prop) {
 return dataArr.map(x => x[prop]);
}
var extract = getSubArray(data, 'speed');

console.log(extract);
```

Comment: Solved using the same steps:
var extract = getSubArray(data, 'speed');

getSubArray(data, indexKey)
{
 return data.map(x => x[indexKey]);
}